# Select distinct slows query

Tags: sql, mariadb

So when I add `DISTINCT` to my query it goes from `0.062s` to `0.152s`?

How can this be?
`Project` is a index in the table `target`, so I don't know how I can speed this process up?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    `Project` AS `Value`
FROM
    `Testreportingdebug`.`Target`
        LEFT JOIN
    `TestJob` ON `Target`.`TestJobId` = `TestJob`.`Id`
WHERE
    `TestJob`.`Engine` = 'SeqZap';
```

Here is my two tables

[image: table]

Comment: `DISTINCT` has a cost.

Comment: BTW, your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. If you really want LEFT JOIN result, move the  `TestJob`.`Engine` condition from WHERE to ON.

Comment: @jarlh okay thanks, when I see small increases in times like this it just raises a red flag in my head, because it might be fast now, but not in 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you surprised?  The database has to do work to remove duplicates.

Assuming that `project` is not duplicated in `target`, you can just use `exists`:

```
select t.project
from Testreportingdebug.Target t
where exists (select 1
              from TestJob tj
              where t.TestJobId = tj.id and tj.Engine = 'SeqZap'
             );
```

However, if `project` is not unique in `Target`, then you still need `distinct`:

```
select distinct t.project
from Testreportingdebug.Target t
where exists (select 1
              from TestJob tj
              where t.TestJobId = tj.id and tj.Engine = 'SeqZap'
             );
```

For this query, you can try an index on `Target(project, TestJobId)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the results is the same. I think the only way to solve this whould be to change the database structure tbh